# combining 20 overloaded subs into one

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with a third-party library interfacing to an *old* database system. There's a method - `CallProg` that calls a "stored procedure" (for lack of a better translation - any Pick users in the crowd?). However, instead of doing something like this:

```
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, ParamArray ProgArgs() As String)
    ...
End Sub
```

or even this:

```
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, Optional Arg1 As String, Optional Arg2 As String ... Optional Arg20 As String)
```

They did this:

```
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName)
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, Arg1 As String)
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, Arg1 As String, Arg2 As String)
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, Arg1 As String, Arg2 As String, Arg3 As String)
...
Public Sub CallProg(ProgName, Arg1 As String, ... Arg20 As String)
```

I'm writing an abstraction class to handle logging in, setting the environment, etc., so it can be used as a generic "helper" class in a number of other projects. Is there any way to wrap the `CallProg` sub that doesn't involve 20 overloads?

Comment: What's wrong with the `Optional` option you have described?

Comment: If I made my helper routine using 20 optionals, I'd still have to have 20 `Case` lines in a `Select Case` statement. I can't call the underlying `CallProg` sub with 1 "real" argument and 20 blank strings, because it'll try passing all 20 arguments to the backend program that expects only one argument.

Comment: I think you could use Reflection.

Comment: I figured it might be something like that. I'll look, but I can't guarantee I won't be back here tomorrow asking for more information...

Comment: One more question before I sleep on this...does the fact that some of the parameters are byval and some are byref make a difference? I ran the GetMethods() command and it returned these:

    (47): {Void CallProg(System.String)}
    (48): {Void CallProg(System.String, System.String ByRef)}
    (49): {Void CallProg(System.String, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)}

etc. The first argument (ProgName) is byval, but everything else is byref, and for some reason `GetMethod("CallProg", {GetType(String), GetType(String)}.ToArray)` returns `nothing`. Is there a connection?

Comment: I'll answer that myself. Apparently, yes, it makes a difference. Running `GetMethod("CallProg", {GetType(String), GetType(String).MakeByRefType}.ToArray)` returned the correct method.

Comment: Yes, that'll make a difference. This is a *very* strange API design. It's not at all clear why they've chosen to make the n+1 parameters `ByRef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very quick idea of how to do it using reflection.  I'm not sure if its the best way but it should work...

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    CallProg("ProgName", {"testArg1", "TestArg2"})

End Sub

Private Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String, ByVal Params As IEnumerable(Of String))

    Dim testClass As New Test1

    Dim methodTypes As List(Of Type) =
        Params.Select(Function(x) GetType(String)).ToList

    methodTypes.Add(GetType(String))

    Dim methodToBeCalled As Reflection.MethodInfo =
        testClass.GetType.GetMethod("CallProg",
                                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
                                    Type.DefaultBinder,
                                    methodTypes.ToArray,
                                    Nothing)


    Dim paramsToPass As New List(Of String)

    paramsToPass.Add(ProgName)
    paramsToPass.AddRange(Params)

    methodToBeCalled.Invoke(testClass, paramsToPass.ToArray)

End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class Test1

```
Public Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String)
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub0 called")
End Sub

Public Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String, ByVal Arg1 As String)
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub1 called")
End Sub

Public Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String, ByVal Arg1 As String, ByVal Arg2 As String)
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub2 called")
End Sub

Public Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String, ByVal Arg1 As String, ByVal Arg2 As String, ByVal Arg3 As String)
    Debug.WriteLine("Sub3 called")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: That's roughly what ended up working; I'll post what I ended up with, too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do what Rene147 suggested:

```
Private _act As New APIClass

Public Sub CallProg(ByVal ProgName As String, ByVal ParamArray ProgArgs() As String)
    Try
        Dim tList As New List(Of Type)
        tList.Add(GetType(String))

        Dim aList As New List(Of String)
        aList.Add(ProgName)

        For Each arg In ProgArgs
            tList.Add(GetType(String).MakeByRefType)
            'tList.Add(GetType(String))    <-- only use this if all the args are ByVal
            aList.Add(arg)
        Next
        Dim typeList As Type() = tList.ToArray
        Dim argList As String() = aList.ToArray

        GetType(APIClass).GetMethod("CallProg", typeList).Invoke(_act, argList)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("Error running program {0}.", ProgName)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's pointless to catch the exception and display an error. You'll see the error message when the exception gets thrown.

Comment: Actually in this case, since we're working with a connection manager that will only allow 5 connections at once (some licensing issue), if I'm debugging and hit an exception and have to reset the program, it's a pain to have to go to the connection manager and close out the connection I was using manually. By catching the exception I can let the class gracefully log out (not shown here) rather than aborting the connection. But I agree - under normal circumstances that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Bizarre. It's unaware that the program was *closed*? Time to switch components, that's one's clearly a dead end. Either way, I wouldn't include hacks like this in a SO answer that's unrelated to the hack...